# Angular unit test pipe, map from service - pipe is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, pipe, observable

I can't get any of my unit tests to run if I use fixture.detectChanges() because of observables I'm initiating in ngOnInit. I've been able to test Observables in other components, but I'm not sure how to get the .pipe(map to work for these. Whenever I do fixture.detectChanges(), it gives the error "this.docService.fileType$.pipe is not a function.

Scaled-down code:

```
fileType$: Observable<FileType>;
isInMainView$: Observable<boolean>;
isInSearchView$: Observable<boolean>;

constructor(private docService: DocService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.fileType$ = this.docService.fileType$
  this.isInMainView$ = this.docService.fileType$.pipe(map((v) => v === 'main'));
  this.isInSearchView$ = this.docService.fileType$.pipe(map((v) => v === 'search'));
}
```

```
let docService: any;

beforeEach(
  waitForAsync(() => {
    const docServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('DocService', ['fileType$']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FileComponent},
      providers: [ { provide: DocService, useValue: docServiceSpy }]
    })
      .compileComponent()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FileComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstances;
        docService = TestBed.inject(DocService);
        docService.fileType$.and.returnValue(of('main'));
      });
  })
 );

 if('should set initial properties, fakeAsync(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
 }));
```

Comment: It looks like you have created a spy but haven't told it to return anything. As I haven't  used Jasmine in a while the docs will give you a more accurate answer than I could off the cuff. You may also need to figure out how to return a promise with a value... https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/spying_on_properties

Comment: It's returning something here: docService.fileType$.and.returnValue(of('main')); That's how I typically return a value but with the addition of the .pipe(map, it need something else.

Comment: Check out this SO post, it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375178/getting-typeerror-pipe-is-not-a-function-while-testing-angular-component-using-o

Comment: I can't see from the code if fileType$ on the docService is a function or a property but suspect from it's name that it may be a property.